# Enviar sms com modem 3g

Tags: java

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em java que envia sms através de um modem usando o RXTX.

Até agora tenho este código:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
    Escreve escreve = new Escreve(queue);


    escreve.out("AT\r\n");
    String saida = queue.take().toString();
    System.out.println("OUTPUT: " + saida);

    if(saida.contains("OK")) {
        //AT+CMGF=1\n
        escreve.out("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
        saida = queue.take().toString();
        System.out.println("OUTPUT: " + saida);

        if(saida.contains("OK")) {
            //"AT+CMGS=\"+"+numero+"\"\n"
            String numero = "xxxxxxxxx";
            escreve.out("AT+CMGS=\"+"+numero+"\"\r\n");
            saida = queue.take().toString();
            System.out.println("OUTPUT: " + saida);

            if(saida.contains(">")) {
                //"Teste de envio de mensagem"+(char)26
                escreve.out("Teste de envio de mensagem\u001a");
                saida = queue.take().toString();
                System.out.println("OUTPUT: " + saida);

            }else {
                System.out.println("Erro");
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("Erro");
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println("Erro");
    }

    //AT+CMGS="+PPAAxxxxxxxx",145\r\n
    //<mensagem>\u001a
}

class Escreve{
private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;

public Escreve(BlockingQueue<String> queue){this.queue = queue;}

public void out(String command) throws Exception{
    CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM9");
    SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(), 1000);
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(460800,
            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
    serialPort.addEventListener(new Listener(serialPort,queue));
    OutputStream outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Já enviou!");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    outputStream.close();
    serialPort.close();

}

class Listener extends Thread implements SerialPortEventListener{
private final SerialPort serialPort;
private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
public Listener(SerialPort serialPort, BlockingQueue<String> queue){
    this.serialPort = serialPort;
    this.queue = queue;
}
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    try{
        InputStream inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case SerialPortEvent.BI:
            System.out.println("1");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.OE:
            System.out.println("2");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.FE:
            System.out.println("3");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.PE:
            System.out.println("4");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.CD:
            System.out.println("5");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
            System.out.println("6");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
            System.out.println("7");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.RI:
            System.out.println("8");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
            System.out.println("9");
            queue.put("NADA");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[100];
            try {
                while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                    queue.put(new String(readBuffer));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Qual o problema?**

Ele corre o programa todo e envia a mensagem (pelo menos não dá erro). No entanto, a mensagem nunca chega ao numero que nós introduzimos.

Após envio de sms, ele não devolve nada.

**NOTA:**
O número que insiro é sem o código do país (+351), se meter código do país, o modem retorna erro.

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLUÇÃO**

- Utilizo a biblioteca RXTX onde podemos fazer o download
  [AQUI](http://fizzed.com/oss/rxtx-for-java) e tirar o windows-x64 na parte dos **Downloads**. Copiar para a pasta do projeto **RXTXcomm.jar**, **rxtxParallel.dll** e **rxtxSerial.dll**.
- Utilizo uma banda larga com um cartão SIM.
- Atenção à porta em que o modem está ligada (COMx), neste caso está ligada na porta COM9. Ver no Device Manager (gestor de dispositivos), na parte dos modem.

**CÓDIGO**

```
public class ErsteSchritte {

private static CommPortIdentifier portId;
private static SerialPort serialPort;
private static OutputStream outputStream;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM9");
    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("Teste", 1000);
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
    serialPort.addEventListener(new Listener(serialPort));


    //AT+CMGF=1\n
    String x1 = "AT+CMGF=1\r\n";
    outputStream.write(x1.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Enviou a primeira.");
    Thread.sleep(1000);


    //"AT+CMGS=\"+"+numero+"\"\n"
    String numero = "+351xxxxxxxxx";
    String x2 = "AT+CMGS=\""+numero+"\",145\r\n";
    outputStream.write(x2.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Envia a segunda.");
    Thread.sleep(1000);


    //"Teste de envio de mensagem"+(char)26
    String mensagem = "MENSAGEM A ENVIAR";
    String x3 = mensagem +"\u001a";
    outputStream.write(x3.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Envia a terceira.");

    Thread.sleep(20000);
    outputStream.close();
    serialPort.close();

    System.out.println("TERMINOU!");

}} 

class Listener extends Thread implements SerialPortEventListener{
private final SerialPort serialPort;

public Listener(SerialPort serialPort){
    this.serialPort = serialPort;
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    try{
        InputStream inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case SerialPortEvent.BI:
            System.out.println("1");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.OE:
            System.out.println("2");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.FE:
            System.out.println("3");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.PE:
            System.out.println("4");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.CD:
            System.out.println("5");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
            System.out.println("6");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
            System.out.println("7");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.RI:
            System.out.println("8");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
            System.out.println("9");
            System.out.println("NADA");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[200];
            try {
                while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                    System.out.println(new String(readBuffer));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```